# How to get the ID as a string from a parent element and compare to another string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML structure:

```
<div id="blah">
    <ul style="...">
        <li><a href="...">...</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have a jQuery selector that targets all `<a>` tags. However, I would like to check if the clicked `<a>` is a child item of the `id="blah"`.

This is what I have so far:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(t) {
    console.info($(this).text());
    if($(this).parent() == 'blah'){
        console.info('Yes, this link has the parent');
    }
});
```

However, the `if` never becomes true and I cannot detect when the link has the specified parent. How do I correctly do this?

Comment: If you only want to run code on a click event on a direct descendent of the element with `id="blah"`, you can amend your selector: `$(document).on('click', '#blah a' function(t) { ... });`

Answer (score 8):

Use `attr()` to get the element attribute value

```
if($(this).parent() == 'blah'){
```

Should be

```
if($(this).parent().attr('id') == 'blah'){
```

```js
$(document).on('click', 'a', function() {
  console.info($(this).text());
  if ($(this).parent().attr('id') == 'blah') {
    console.info('Yes, this link has the parent');
  }

  return false; // To stop page redirection
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="blah">
  <ul style="...">
    <li><a href="...">...</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

You can also use

```
if($(this).parent().is('#blah'){
```

---

> I would like to check if the clicked  is a child item of the id="blah".

```
if ($(this).parent('#blah').length) {
```

This will check for the direct parent, if you want to check for **ancestor**

```
if ($(this).closest('#blah').length) {
```

Comment: The example doesn't have the `<a>` tag as a direct child of the element with id `blah`.

Comment: @Phylogenesis That's why I've added option to check if the `#blah` is ancestor of the clicked element. Check the bottom of answer

Comment: I see that now. The edit wasn't visible when I made my comment.

Comment: @Phylogenesis As the explanation and the code in the question don't support each other, I've added both the answers :)